# Can not Discover any available bluetooth device using React Native

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I can get a list of available bluetooth devices using OS bluetooth manager.But I can not discover any avaiable bluetooth device using react-native-ble-manager or using react-native-ble-plx.

Comment: Please add some details and the code you are running will be also helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: I just use the demo basic example of react-native-ble-manager.    https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager